# Certain Dragon NaturallySpeaking voice commands not working in Word, Excel

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-word-2007, dragon-naturally-speaking

I am running Windows Vista, with MS Office 2007.  I used to have Dragon NaturallySpeaking 10, and I noticed that certain commands, such as "Undo That, Italicize that, Bold that," etc. no longer worked, and I cannot use cell-selection commands in Excel.  I was told that Dragon ver.10 is no longer supported, and it was likely that certain Windows/Office updates may have disabled functionality.  So, I went ahead and purchased Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12...*but I am still having the same problem!*

I have already checked the COM add-ins for Word and Excel:  both are present AND active.  I have applied all Windows updates for Vista and the .NET framework Dragon seems to use, all to no avail.  I am severely frustrated and at my wits' end.  *What the heck is wrong with this, and how do I fix it?*  I would appreciate any serious assistance.  Thanks!

I'd like to provide additional information for clarity, since I've been asked this question:  Dragon clearly understands each command I give it, as the command is correctly echoed in the dictation box (just like any other dictation/command I speak to it)...it's just that the command is not performed for some reason.

UPDATE:  I have an excerpt from my log file that may help:

> 01:05:02 S2: Starting recognition ...
>   01:05:02 LOG (Perf): DgnSAPI paused -> BeginUtt = 367 msec
>   01:05:03 E:\work\1200relmob\shared\dgnass.cpp(1775): CoCreateInstance(clsid=clsidScriptId,iid=IID_IActiveScript) returned The specified module could not be found.
>   01:05:03  (ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND, 126).
>   01:05:03 Error: The following exception triggered by cmd 'undo that', script 'on error resume next
>   01:05:03 CmdStart
>   01:05:03 CmdUndo
>   01:05:03 CmdEnd
>   01:05:03 '
>   01:05:03 COM returned an unexpected error code: Details are The specified module could not be found.
>   01:05:03  (ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND, 126)

Comment: Can you reprogram dragon so it bypasses the com add-ins sort of a global hot key? If you speak undo that, it'll execute ctrl+z?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @sunk818!  The problem is I would have to do that for an extensive list of commands:  italicize, bold, underline, backspace _x_ characters, end (go to end of line)...and I have no idea how I would enable Dragon to select cells in Excel with this method!  This bug/fault seriously hampers functionality.  X-(

Comment: I know F2 can edit a cell. Selecting a cell, you'd have to just move to it. You can also use F5 and speak the specific cell you want to navigate to.

Answer (score 0):

Buy an old copy of Office 2003 and a copy of Dragon NaturallySpeaking that supports that version. If you want to be compatible with the newer .docx, .xlsx, or .pptx formats, you can use the [Office 2003 Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3). I suggest going back to a setup that used to work for you and stick with it. Hopefully, the security updates do not disable the software and it has to do with versions of Office and/or Dragon NaturallySpeaking.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a viable option for me for numerous logistical reasons, including the fact that having two copies of Office (2003, 2007) on the same machine is not advisable and would not be a good use of the resources I have.  In addition, I have no idea whether it is the updates from Vista or Office that are causing the issue.  However, based on what I have been able to obtain from the Log File, I am beginning to suspect something else.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to working, and I'm trying to recall my efforts so that I can share them with anyone else who may be suffering from the same symptoms.

I found that the problem lay with some interconnected factors.  Dragon NaturallySpeaking uses some sort of scripting which ties into Windows' vbscript to achieve its actions.  If I'm remembering correctly, it's possible that an antivirus program such as Avast *MAY* be inhibiting this from happening.

You'll need to make a change to the Windows registry on the impacted machine.    *If you are unfamiliar with working in the Windows registry (and even if you ARE familiar), I strongly advise that you create a backup of your current registry file first...it's a simple process and there are instructions available online.*

1. Navigate to
   **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{B54F3741-5B07-11cf-A4B0-00AA004A55E8}**
2. Double-click on that key to expand it and see its subkeys.
3. Click on **InProcServer32**
4. The following elements of InProcServer32 should have these values...if not, double-click on them to make the appropriate changes.

   - **(Default)**...*Type* should be **REG_SZ**...*Data* should be **C:\Windows\system32\vbscript.dll**
   - **Default Engine**...values should be the same as above
   - **Threading Model**...*Type* should be **REG_SZ**...*Data* should be **Both**

I hope this helps someone!